# Azure Graph API - Can't create local account

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a "LocalAccount" in a B2C domain as documented in here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I am using the azure-graph node package and the payload of my request looks like in the MSDN article.

The request is:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "Alex Wu",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "userName",
      "value": "AlexW"
    },
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "AlexW@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error: Error "'userPrincipalName' cannot be null or undefined in 'parameters'." occurred in serializing the payload

I think the error comes from the node package. Does the node graph api client support LocalAccounts?

Comment: Did you specify api-version=1.6?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I did. I ended up not using the azure-graph sdk. I am sending a simple POST to the endpoint with the right fields and everything works.